# ProgressDialog.show() is not showing the progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am trying to display a  progress dialog inside a fragment.But progressbar.show() do not have any effect.However,I noticed a strange behaviour,if i call showPopUp() method twice,it does show the progress dialog,but unable to dismiss().

```
package com.snapbizz.snapdashboard.Tabs.v1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.snapbizz.snapdashboard.Core.v1.SalesData;
import com.snapbizz.snapdashboard.R;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class DashBoardSalesTab extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout salesListContainer, salesBarConatainer;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    SalesData salesData;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sales_page_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void showPopUp() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading the page...");
        progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
        progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    public void synchronizeScrollers() {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.page_scroller).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table_scroller).getParent()
                        .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table_scroller).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void renderSalesGraph(List<String[]> values, Float totalSumY) throws Exception {

        salesBarConatainer.removeAllViews();
        for (String[] value : values) {
            View barView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_char_item_layout, salesBarConatainer, false);
            float sumOfSalesForTheDay = Float.parseFloat((value[0] == null) ? "0" : value[0]);
            float weightofBar = sumOfSalesForTheDay / totalSumY;
            barView.findViewById(R.id.bar_y).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, weightofBar));

            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_y)).setText(
                    (sumOfSalesForTheDay == 0.0f ? "" :
                            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.rupee_symbol) + sumOfSalesForTheDay + "")
            );
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date renderingDate = inputFormat.parse(value[2]);
            String[] date = outputFormat.format(renderingDate).split("-");
            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_x_date)).setText(date[0] + " " + date[1]);
            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_x_year)).setText(date[2]);
            salesBarConatainer.addView(barView);
        }
    }

    public void renderSalesGraphForMonths(List<String[]> values, Float totalSumY) throws Exception {
        LinearLayout salesBarConatainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bars_container);
        salesBarConatainer.removeAllViews();
        for (String[] value : values) {
            View barView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_char_item_layout, salesBarConatainer, false);
            float sumOfSalesForTheDay = Float.parseFloat((value[0] == null) ? "0" : value[0]);
            float weightofBar = sumOfSalesForTheDay / totalSumY;
            barView.findViewById(R.id.bar_y).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, weightofBar));

            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_y)).setText(
                    (sumOfSalesForTheDay == 0.0f ? "" :
                            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.rupee_symbol) + sumOfSalesForTheDay + "")
            );
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
            Date renderingDate = inputFormat.parse(value[2]);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, renderingDate.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            barView.setOnClickListener(new MonthBarClickListener(cal));
            String[] date = outputFormat.format(renderingDate).split("-");
            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_x_date)).setText(date[0]);
            ((TextView) barView.findViewById(R.id.value_x_year)).setText(date[1]);
            salesBarConatainer.addView(barView);
        }
    }

    public String[] addTOSalesTable(String date, boolean header) throws Exception {
        List<String[]> values = salesData.getSalesTableData(date);
        String[] value = values.get(0);
        String[] newValue = {value[0], value[1], date};
        String totalSales = (value[0] == null) ? "0" : value[0];
        String totalCredit = (value[1] == null) ? "0" : value[1];
        String totalCash = (Float.parseFloat(totalSales) - Float.parseFloat(totalCredit)) + "";
        String rupeeSymbol = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.rupee_symbol);
        if (!header) {
            View salesRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sales_page_table_row_layout, salesListContainer, false);
            ((TextView) (salesRow.findViewById(R.id.sale_date))).
                    setText(date);
            ((TextView) (salesRow.findViewById(R.id.sales_total_sale))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalSales);
            ((TextView) (salesRow.findViewById(R.id.sales_total_cash))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalCash);
            ((TextView) (salesRow.findViewById(R.id.sales_total_credit))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalCredit);
            ((TextView) (salesRow.findViewById(R.id.sales_ttoal_coupon))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + "0");
            if (salesListContainer.getChildCount() % 2 != 0) {
                salesRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.table_row_alternate_color));
            }
            salesListContainer.addView(salesRow);
        } else {
            ((TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_header_total_sales))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalSales);
            ((TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_header_total_cash))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalCash);
            ((TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_header_total_credit))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + totalCredit);
            ((TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_header_total_coupon))).
                    setText(rupeeSymbol + " " + "0");
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            Date presentDate = new Date();
            ((TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_header_day))).
                    setText(date.contentEquals(dateFormat.format(presentDate)) ? "Today" : date);
        }
        return newValue;
    }

    public void getMonths() throws Exception {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM");

        List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
        float totalSumY = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, (i == 0) ? 0 : -1);
            String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            String[] value = salesData.getSalesDataForMonth(date);
            String[] newValue = {value[0] == null ? "0" : value[0], value[1] == null ? "0" : value[1], date};
            totalSumY += Float.parseFloat(value[0] == null ? "0" : value[0]);
            values.add(newValue);
        }
        renderSalesGraphForMonths(values, totalSumY);
    }

    public void initChart() {
        FrameLayout dayButton = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.day_button);
        FrameLayout monthButton = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.month_button);
        dayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_day_text)).setTextColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_darkblue)
                    );
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_day_text)).
                            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border_active));

                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_month_text)).setTextColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.default_text_color)
                    );
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_month_text)).
                            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border));

                    generateTablesRows(Calendar.getInstance(), 60, -1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        monthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_month_text)).setTextColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_darkblue)
                    );
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_month_text)).
                            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border_active));

                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_day_text)).setTextColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.default_text_color)
                    );
                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_day_text)).
                            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border));
                    getMonths();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void generateTablesRows(Calendar cal, int limit, int increment) throws Exception {
        salesListContainer.removeAllViews();
        float totalSumY = 0.0f;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        List<String[]> barGraphValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, (i == 0) ? 0 : increment);
            String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            String[] value = addTOSalesTable(date, (i == 0) ? true : false);
            totalSumY += Float.parseFloat((value[0] == null) ? "1" : value[0]);
            barGraphValues.add(value);
        }
        renderSalesGraph(barGraphValues, totalSumY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        showPopUp();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        salesListContainer = (LinearLayout) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sales_list_container));
        salesListContainer.removeAllViews();
        salesBarConatainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bars_container);
        salesBarConatainer.removeAllViews();
        new SalesTabLoader().execute();

    }

    public class MonthBarClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        Calendar cal;

        public MonthBarClickListener(Calendar cal) {
            this.cal = cal;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                //new SalesAsyncTask(cal).execute(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),1);
                generateTablesRows(cal, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SalesTabLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            salesData = new SalesData(getContext());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            try {
                initChart();
                generateTablesRows(Calendar.getInstance(), 60, -1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                synchronizeScrollers();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try getActivity() in progressdialog builder

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

And if you wish to customize your dialog and put self created Layout in it.

```
/**
 * Created by vivek on 18/10/16.
 */
public class CustomDialog {
    private static Dialog dialog;
    private static Context context;

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Comman progress dialog ... initiates with this
     *
     * @param message
     * @param title
     */
    public static void showProgressDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        if (dialog == null)
        {
            dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_loader);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isProgressDialogRunning() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss comman progress dialog
     */
    public static void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
} // End of main class over here ...
```

Comment: Tried both,didn't work :( Any other way to get the progress dialog up :(

Comment: If this didn't worked for you, then you  must check your code. Some thing else is barring it to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:-

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

with

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: there is something wrong with your code..I have checked it at my end your showPopup() method is correct. Try calling this somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

May be. you are showing two `progressdialog` and both of that `progressbar` on screen.. but when you dismiss your `progressbar` at that time the previous one is override by other one before you dismiss first one .. so the firstone is always in screen. that's the issue.

Comment: interesting thought..But progress dialog doesn't popup ,when i call showPopup() method once,it popup when i call showPopup() twice. What do you want to say about that?

Comment: @abhishekramkrishna when you call showPopup() twice then previous progressbar is in memory and also on screen. but its reference is override by the second time call of showPopup(). so now in you screen or activity there is two progressbar 1st and 2nd. and now you have reference of 2nd progressbar in your variable not 1st one. so when you dismiss the progressbar it will dismiss only 2nd one. and 1st progressbar always on screen until you finish your activity because you dont have any reference in any variable for 1st progressbar. got it??

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything.But none of the answers solved the issue.However,i solved it by overriding onResume() method in the fragment.

Thanks All.